# Input similar lines of code with minimal changes

Tags: intellij-14

I remember that there was feature in VIM (can't remember the name) where you can input multiple lines of code that are similar but with minimal differences with each other. This is useful since instead of copying/pasting multiple code where you change each of them, you use this feature with only writing the changes

EX:

```
@something I write here (all the same)
private int [NAME OF VARIABLE THAT CHANGES]

@something I write here (all the same)
private int [NAME OF VARIABLE THAT CHANGES]

....
```

I'm using Intellij and I'm wondering if it has something similar

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Snipmate](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate) or [Ultisnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips).  Personally, I use Ultisnips.